# Bandwidth control with TC for clients yet to be connected

Tags: strongswan, tc, bandwidth-control, ikev2

I have applied bandwidth control using TC and iptables using [this](https://linuxscriptshub.com/bandwidth-control-on-ikev2-with-tc-and-iptables/) tutorial on my Strongswan VPN server.
The bandwidth control works fine ONLY if that specific client is already connected. 
For example: In my Strongswan VPN server, i am trying to limit bandwidth of server 10.24.24.1.

The **PROBLEM is**  bandwidth limit will only work if this client is connected and then i run the bandwidth script. 
Otherwise, 
If i run the script first, and then later the client connects , the bandwidth control doesn't work. Is this some kind of requirement that this script works for connected clients only ?

My script looks like this

```
ikev2=24 #eth0
echo tc qdisc del dev $main root >>tcrules
echo tc qdisc add dev $main root handle 1: htb >>tcrules
for i in {1..254}
do
##udp1194
echo iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.$ikev2.$ikev2.$i -j MARK --set-mark 1$i >> mark
echo iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.$ikev2.$ikev2.$i -j MARK --set-mark 1$i >> mark
echo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:1$i htb rate 1mbit ceil 1mbit >> tcrules
echo tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1$i sfq perturb 10 >> tcrules
echo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 handle 1$i fw flowid 1:1$i >> tcrules
done
```